# How to make repeatable template in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want make WPF application like this picture..

[image]

I want make data entry application with database structure like here (Columns)

```
A  | B |  C |  D |  ...  | Z
```

And I want make repeatable section to insert whether Column `2` and Column `3`  is optional. So it's like horizonal rows in my database.

How can I make structure layout like this in WPF with databinding? I want make my `Textbox A` will have data binding to `A` in my database Textbox B will be bind with `B` and etc..

How the best approach to doing this...? Help me..

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would downvote this question. +1 to undo that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to show a list of lists.

You could simplify your database table to something like this:

```
Id | ColumnIndex | RowIndex | Value
```

Your query could look like this:

```
GroupedValues = table.GroupBy(x => x.ColumnIndex);
```

Then you can use an ItemsControl with ItemsPanel set to a horizontally oriented StackPanel and the ItemTemplate set to a standard (vertical) ItemsControl, like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedValues}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This code is not tested but hopefully it gives you the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. I got some clue to handle this matter.. But I don't want to simplify my database because it has different value for each textbox..